# A doubt about the proof about the differentiability of the limits of sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, sequence-of-function

I'm reading a theorem about the differentiability of the limits of sequences of functions:

> [image]

and its proof:

> [image]
>   [image]

---

1. The Mean Value Theorem is as follows:

> [image]

Should it be $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(a)-f_{n}^{\prime}(a)(x-a)\right| \leq \sup _{0<t<1}\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))-f_{n}^{\prime}(a)\right|\color{blue}{|1-0|}$$ rather than $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{n}(a)-f_{n}^{\prime}(a)(x-a)\right| \leq \sup _{0<t<1}\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))-f_{n}^{\prime}(a)\right|\color{blue}{|x-a|}$$ ?

2. In a similar manner, should it be $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)-\left(f_{n}(a)-f(a)\right)\right| \le \color{blue}{|1-0|} \sup _{0<t<1}\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))-f^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))\right|$$ rather than $$\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)-\left(f_{n}(a)-f(a)\right)\right| \le \color{blue}{r} \sup _{0<t<1}\left|f_{n}^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))-f^{\prime}(a+t(x-a))\right|$$?
3. I would like to confirm my understanding about how 2.1 implies $$f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)=o(|x-a|) \quad(x \rightarrow a)$$

Let $M_x = \sup _{0<t<1}|g(a+t(x-a))-g(a)|$. Then $$\begin{aligned} \lim_{x \to a} M_x &= \lim_{x \to a} \sup _{0<t<1} |g(a+t(x-a))-g(a)| \\&= \sup _{0<t<1} \lim_{x \to a} \ |g(a+t(x-a))-g(a)|\\ &= \sup _{0<t<1} 0 \\ &=0\end{aligned}$$

It follows from 2.1 that $$\frac{|f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|} \le \sup _{0<t<1}|g(a+t(x-a))-g(a)| = M_x$$

and thus $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{|f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|} \le  \lim_{x \to a} M_x = 0$$

and consequently $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{|f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)|}{|x-a|} = \lim_{x \to a} \left | \frac{f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)}{x-a} \right | = 0$$

and consequently $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)-g(a)(x-a)}{x-a} = 0$$, which means $g(a) =f'(a)$

---

**My question:**

Could you please confirm of my above understanding is correct? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Is this from Amann-Escher?

Comment: That's it @ThomasShelby :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow E,t\mapsto f_n(a+t(x-a))-tf_n'(a)(x-a)$ then
$$|\frac{\phi(1)-\phi(0)}{1-0}|=|f_n(x)-f_n'(a)(x-a)-f_n(a)|\leq\sup_{0<t<1}|\phi'(t)|$$
and using the chain rule differentiating with respect to $t$ You get
$$|\phi'(t)|=|f_n'(a+t(x-a))(x-a)-f_n'(a)(x-a)|\leq |f_n'(a+t(x-a)))-f_n'(a)||x-a|.$$
Similar with the other function. The factor $x-a$ is the differentiation of the inner function.

Comment: I'm not really careful in taking the derivative w.r.t $t$ :( Could you please confirm if my third understanding is correct?

Comment: That is clearly correct!

Comment: For clarification: I assume You know the chain rule. Say the inner function is $h(t)=a+t(x-a)$ then $\frac{\partial f_n\circ h}{t}(t)=f_n'(h(t))h'(t)$ and $h'(t)=x-a$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness :)

Comment: You're welcome!